# How I can set keep screen on and full screen flag?

Tags: android, layoutparams, android-screen, android-windowmanager

fullscreen in my app and I write this code :

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                       .
                       .
                       .
```

And keep screen on in my app  I write this code in layout :

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Although it is not always , sometimes error me like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:381)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can I do? I write true code? 
THANKS...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

super.onCreate must be called first....

You can do it programatically:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it via your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: try and let us know the result

Comment: i dont know about screenOnflag i used the above code to make full screen but not used any flag

Comment: ok it is true full screen . And I want to know other thing that my screen always be open .

Answer (score 3):

WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN depreciated on API >= 30 (R)
Suggest to use this method to check.

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
   window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
} else {
   window.setFlags(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
     )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add in activity in AndroidMenifest.xml file

```
 android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/customTheme" >
```

and remove the following if exist before setContentView

```
boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable Fullscreen:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To enable screen on:

```
getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | 
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```